# how to make any component like button or input field adjust to any Screen by default in react-native

Tags: react-native

I want how to fit the button to any screen with no alignment and view change. I am having problem with button that is perfectly aligned in on emulator device and in turn alignment differs when using another emulator device

```
<Button
    textColor="white"
    buttonColor={themeColor}
    radius="25"
    style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
    width="335"
    title="Sign In"
    onPress={this._login}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way of styling you are using is static to the particular device on which you are having your output.
you should use a dynamic way of styling rather.
you can use % in your styles that can have that % of the part of screen available.
for eg.

```
<Button styles={{margin:'2%', width:'70%',height:'20%' }}/>
```

as follows.

you can also use the Dimension from react-native.
for eg.

```
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const { width: WIDTH, height: HEIGHT } = Dimensions.get('window');
const StylesNew = StyleSheet.create({

   Styles: {
        width: WIDTH / 8,
        height: HEIGHT / 20,
        marginVertical:HEIGHT/30
    },
```